# Why isn't my code running the whole program but not producing any errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to calculate the digits of a rational number that I get from the user.
The problem is that even though there is no errors in the code, the program running only part of the code. I'm working in Visual Studio.

```
int sumDigits(int a);

// main function
int main()
{
    int ratioNum;
    // Ask from the user to enter a rational number
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a rational number: ";
    // Get the number from the user
    cin >> ratioNum;
    // Inform the user what is the sum of the digits
    cout << "The sum of the digits are: " << sumDigits(ratioNum) << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}

// Definition of function
int sumDigits(int a)
{
    int digit = 0, sum = 0;
    // As long as number is bigger than 0, continue
    while (a > 0)
    {
        // Define a new verible - digit, as a number mudolo 10
        digit = a % 10;
    }
    // kick out the units digit that we used
    a / 10;
    // Sum the digits of the number
    sum = digit + a; 
    // Return sum to the main function
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: "Rational number" isn't a synonym of integral number. `1/2` is a rational number, but not an integer. Note though that during the `while` loop you never modify `a`, so the value the loop condition evalyates to never changes; therefore the loop simply never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You need `a /= 10` instead of `a / 10`, and you need it *inside* the loop. Otherwise the loop will run forever because `a` never gets modified inside of it, so it can never become `0`.

<sub>This will fix the infinite looping issue but the result will still not be correct. Why that is would be a different question though, and I'd invite you to learn proper debugging first (google how to debug C)! This will help you a lot more than copying a solution from here.</sub>

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Then you should probably comment the question and not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't running the whole program because of these lines:

```
while (a > 0)
{
    // Define a new verible - digit, as a number mudolo 10
    digit = a % 10;
}
```

Inside the while loop, you're only assigning the value to the `digit` variable, but not changing the value of `a`, so the value of `a` always remains `greater than 0`. So your code gets stuck inside the while loop.

Answer (score -2):

You should write

```
// kick out the units digit that we used
    a /= 10;
```

Comment: Steel ain't working